# Paypal does not show item list [Multiple] after redirection to Paypal Website by SetExpressCheckout method call

Tags: java, paypal

I made a successful SetExpressCheckout call with following details and code redirects user to PayPal after getting an ACK success from Paypal Server, I expect to show redirected user itemized details on PayPal page with shipping and discount amount as well.

SetExpressCheckout Request Detail

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&
VERSION=93&
PWD=<PASSWORD>&
USER=<USER>&
SIGNATURE=<SIGNATURE>&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=85.0&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&
ReturnUrl=<REDIRECT_URL>&
CANCELURL=<CANCEL_URL>&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAME0=Electronics+Gift+Card&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NUMBER0=0&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT0=85.00&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_QTY0=1&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital&
BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard
```

**Currently above request do not include shipping amount but i have one in it when it has some physical item.**

[image: PayPal Page After Redirection]

[Similar Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601784/line-items-on-the-paypal-express-checkout-using-paypal-payments-advanced-and-th)

The above question only lead me to PayPal MTs Support and they have enabled my line item support. but still Paypal do not show item detail as shown in the figure.

what should i do so PayPal will show all the items [< 11] on the PayPal page.

by seeing all the above detail am i doing anything wrong ?

fill free to ask me any missing information from above description.

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line item support is enabled for Express Checkout by default afaik. So what you probably enabled when you say you enabled it was line item details for Payflow.. but that's besides the point.

Getting to your answer, your  line item details are listed with *n* as the index for the payment, which [should be replaced with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 or 10, depending on which payment the items belong to. (Look into PayPal's parallel payments if you want more information, but do it later once you understand more about the basics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946709/what-do-the-n-and-m-stand-for-in-the-paypal-api-variables-like-l-paymentrequest). So basically, to fix your issue, you replace the 'n' with '0' for each line item parameter, minus the quotes.  See below:

### Will not show line item details

```
USER=sgtpooki@**********
PWD=***************
SIGNATURE=********************
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
VERSION=*************
RETURNURL=***********
CANCELURL=************
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=85.00 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=test EC payment 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAME0=Electronics+Gift+Card 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NUMBER0=0 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT0=85.00 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_QTY0=1 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital 
BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard
```

### Will show line item details

```
USER=sgtpooki@**********
PWD=***************
SIGNATURE=********************
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
VERSION=*************
RETURNURL=***********
CANCELURL=************
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=85.00 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=test EC payment 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Electronics+Gift+Card 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=0 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=85.00 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital 
BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard
```

Remember that to get line item details for EC (this is also when the EC is being generated *through* payflow) you must send at least the name, quantity, and amount. With your code, PayPal wasn't recognizing that you sent any of them, because 'n' is an invalid payment request index.